# Cannot install google colab using pip install google-colab

Tags: python-3.x, pip, jupyter, google-colaboratory

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [15 lines of output]
      C:\Users\Himanshu Pant\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y8as7upo\pandas_ff2b7ab2a7de42a7b658073b8550bf62\setup.py:12: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html        import pkg_resources
      C:\Users\Himanshu Pant\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py:80: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
              If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      error in pandas setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected end or semicolon (after version specifier)
          pytz >= 2011k
               ~~~~~~~^
```

Using `pip install google-colab` For the jupyter notebook leads to the error above.

What is the fix here?

Comment: Please post the complete output, not just that excerpt